# Get edited posts

Tags: disqus

I'm using the [disqus api](http://disqus.com/api/docs/posts/list/) to get all the posts and using the cursor to do the pagination, I store them in my database.

The problem is if someone writes a post and my application gets it and stores is in the database, and gets the next cursor (and store it for the next iteration), and then this post is edited, I have no way to get it again.

Is there a way to get posts by edited datetime instead of creation datetime? Or another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat tricky since you can't get results by the time they were edited. About the only solution right now is to store the "isEdited" boolean with each comment, and occasionally run through the recent results and look for any changes. You can see this value in the json under `"isEdited": true`

Of course you would miss any followup edits, but the vast majority of edited comments are only edited once. Even then, most edits occur within the first hour of the comment being posted. Assuming you're only doing this for backup purposes, you might be able to get around this entirely by just delaying your sync to comments that are, say, a week old.

Comment: i need to get the edited posts because i'm using my own moderation application to moderate all my social media, your solution is logical but not suficient for my needs, thanks though :)

Comment: Understood, it's definitely something for us to consider. I figured I'd throw out what we have right now, though.